# Using different classes (one imported and one defined) with the same name in a module

Tags: python, python-import

```
from .models import User, AuctionListing, Comment, Bids, Category, Watchlist, Activities, Winners
```

and

```
class Comment(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Comment', 'class': 'listing_textarera'
    }))
```

Class name is `Comment`.

I have imported from `.models` and individual definition as above.

Here is in `views.py` module.

This two `Comment` class are different.

How can I using each one (Comment is imported from `models.py` or Class is defined here) separately?

May I refer each one individually?

May experience is here:

```
c = Comment(message=message, user=request.user, listing=listing)
```

Which throws an error:

> got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as` keyword to import the class `Comment` with a different name, like:

```
import .models.Comment as MComment
```

It will avoid all the misinterpretation using them.